# Split file into unequal chunks in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I wish to split a large file (with ~ 17M Lines of Strings) into multiple files with varying number of lines in each chunk. Would it be possible to send in an array to the **'*split -l*'** command like this:

```
[
 1=>1000000,
 2=>1000537,
 ...
]
```

so as to send those many number of lines to each chunk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a compound command:

```
{
  head -n 10000 > output1
  head -n   200 > output2
  head -n  1234 > output3
  cat > remainder
} < yourbigfile
```

This also works with loops:

```
{
  i=1
  for n in 10000 200 1234
  do
      head -n $n > output$i
      let i++
  done
  cat > remainder
} < yourbigfile
```

This does not work on OS X, where `head` reads and discards additional output.

Comment: I've tried this but I can't get it to work. Does it have to be a particular shell? Here's my output [pastiebin](http://pastiebin.com/?page=p&id=5112bf8411caa)

Comment: It has to be a `head` that doesn't read and discard output. GNU coreutils head seeks back if it reads too much.

Comment: You might want to add that to your answer - as my shiny Mac didn't do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

The `split` command does not have that capability, so you'll have to use a different tool,
or write one of your own.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed` by getting another script to generate the `sed` commands for you.

```
# split_gen.py
use strict;
my @limits = ( 100, 250, 340,999);
my $filename = "joker";

my $start = 1;
foreach my $end (@limits) {
    print qq{sed -n '$start,${end}p;${end}q' $filename > $filename.$start-$end\n};
    $start = $end + 1;
}
```

Run thus `perl split_gen.py` giving:

```
sed -n '1,100p;100q' joker > joker.1-100
sed -n '101,250p;250q' joker > joker.101-250
sed -n '251,340p;340q' joker > joker.251-340
sed -n '341,999p;999q' joker > joker.341-999
```

If you're happy with the command then you can

```
perl split_gen.py | sh
```

Then enjoy the wait as it may be slow with big files.